# I can't see the next button (ubuntu installation on vmware)

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox, display-resolution, vmware

I am trying to install Ubuntu 64-bit on my VMWare Workstation 12. I have already done this on my desktop.

The problem is when I try to install it on my laptop, I cannot see the next button. The next button was only partially visible on my desktop as well. I am stuck at the "who are you" part.

Comment: Did you fill all the details - Password? Username?

Comment: yes....I just need to be able to see the next button. it's not visible because of the screen resolution. but I selected the biggest screen resolution.

Comment: What about selecting a *smaller* screen resolution?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you include a screenshot or a more detailed description of the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: Normally changing the screen resolution *in* the live system fixes this. But it [seems like](https://askubuntu.com/questions/755196/i-cant-see-the-next-button-ubuntu-installation-on-vmware/951094#comment1127275_755196) there were few choices. There's almost always a better way than using the keyboard to move the installer windows around (as described in answers), but there's no way to know what else might've worked here. Sometimes the resolution can be increased with `xrandr`. Sometimes the VM's settings can be adjusted. So I suggest we avoid closing other questions as duplicates of this one.

Answer (score 15):

I faced this in many occasions when using VirtualBox in low resolution, when dealing with both ubiquity (Ubuntu installer) or Debian installer.

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to move window (***do not click yet***), then use either the mouse or keyboard arrow keys to move the window around until you can see the buttons.
- Left-click when you have the window positioned where you want it. This will lock the window in place until the next time you press Alt+F7

Click the required button or fill the needed info. You should only need to do this during the install phase, however. Many people have a subsequent issue after install of the screen size/resolution being too small and not adjusting with screen. *This can be corrected by **installing Guest Additions** after installing Ubuntu.*

Comment: This was the only thing that worked on `Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS` in 2022! For clarity, press `ALT`+`F7` (in Windows) and then DON'T CLICK! A hand appears and makes you think you should click to drag, but NO! -- Just drag the mouse around until you can see the buttons. Only click when you are happy with the window's position. The window will not be locked in place until the next time you press Alt+F7

Comment: * the window WILL be locked in place

Answer (score 3):

Use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to move to the next button.  Pressing it a few times will cycle it through all buttons on the screen depending on where you are on said screen.

Comment: This works sometimes, if there is only one button at the bottom. If there is more than one you will have to press Tab more than once and go by trial and error, hoping that if you hit the wrong invisible button nothing awful will happen.

Answer (score 1):

In the window where you are installing the Ubuntu VM, double click at the top and the window gets smaller. Now you can move the window around and get to the buttons.

Comment: I've having the same issue with 17.04 and vmware Fusion v8 on mac osx  sierra 10.12.6. It's definitely not an issue of the vmware window just not being big enough, the ubuntu window is chopped on where the left button ("Cancel"?) starts to appear.

Answer (score 0):

use the scroll bar on the side of vmware (may need to specify custom resolution). or when you make the image specify the iso and VMware should be able to auto-install ubuntu for you if my memory serves me right...

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem and got this answer online and it worked. Hold down left-Alt then left click anywhere in the window to move it.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue in ubuntu 16 gnome

1. From live CD run like trial, not install
2. Then you can select your monitor size inside Ubuntu: left click and display settings
   Note: VBox will fit to this selected size
3. Install ubuntu as usual: Press 'windows button' from keyboard or activities from left/top corner and you can see from left menu the install shortcut